# 3D ImageCooccurrence

Tags: image-processing, image, image3d

I'd like to compute `ImageCooccurence` for an `Image3D` object. Mathematica advertises that "Now essentially any operation possible for 2D images also works for 3D images." https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-10/enhanced-3d-image-processing/

I've defined a 3D Kernel and a 3D image as such:

```
kernel3d = {
  {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0}},
  {{0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0}},
  {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}};
image3d = Image3D[RandomReal[1, {5, 5, 5}]];
```

When I run `ImageCooccurrence[image3d,10,kernel3d]`, Mathematica just reports that the the input should be an `Image.`

Is there any ImageCooccurrence extension for `Image3D`? If not, does anyone have any suggestions for quickly accomplishing this?

Comment: I'm struggling to understand what `ImageCoocurrence` actually does. From the docs _ImageCooccurrence[image,n] returns an n*n matrix m whose elements mij represent the probability of all occurrences of a pixel with intensity i to the left or bottom of a pixel with intensity j, assuming all pixels to lie in one of n successive bins._ - represent the probability of ... what? Also what is the kernel for? If somebody could take this sentence and dumb it down a bit we might have an answer.

Comment: Say you have a 4x4 2D Image with just two colors: black and white. We can assign this image n=2 bins (one black, one white). Say this image has vertical stripes that are one pixel wide (bl, wh, bl, wh). If the kernel is {{0,0,0},{0,0,1},{0,0,0}}, ImageCooccurrence will check the pixel immediately to the right of every pixel. For the black bin, this yields 0 black neighbors and 8 white. For the white bin, this yields 4 black neighbors and 0 white. The resulting matrix is {{0,8},{4,0}}. The func then just divides by 12 (total number of neighbors) to return {{0,0.6},{0.3,0}}

Comment: Try ```ImageCooccurrence[Image[Table[{0, 1, 0, 1}, {i, 0, 4}]], 2, {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0}}]```

Answer (score 3):

> Is there any ImageCooccurrence extension for Image3D?

No.

```
GeneralUtilities`PrintDefinitions@ImageCooccurrence
```

[image]

[image]